# Lock access to /admin url for live site (but not staging site) for specific roles/users

Tags: kentico

I have a kentico site built with portal engine and have staging and production/live environments. I'm wondering if it's possible to restrict/lock access to the admin area (/admin url) of the live site based on roles or privilege levels. Their access to staging site should remain the same. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0):

There is no out of the box setting for this - you would need to use two sets of users and roles, separated in each environment and disable staging of users and roles. It is not possible to have the same user/role object on two environments with different behavior.